# Submit a form onsubmit making first a control with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm making a project that will save some data from a form in a db. I have to check if these data are compiled correctly (key is necessary and at least one value) and if the key already exists in the db. The first part is already done, it controls well the parameters, but when I have to submit it doesn't do it. Here is the code:

```
function insertControl() {

var insertError= $("#insertError");
var key = $.trim($("input[id='key']").val());
var value1 = $.trim($("textarea[id='valueITA']").val());
var value2 = $.trim($("textarea[id='valueGBR']").val());
var value3 = $.trim($("textarea[id='valueAUS']").val());
var value4 = $.trim($("textarea[id='valueUSA']").val());
var value5 = $.trim($("textarea[id='valueFRA']").val());
var id = $.trim($("input[id='control']").val()); //it is to see if i'm editing a label or just creating, in html there is an imput type hidden, if i press edit from the search function it passes the id in this input, else it is ""
var controlled= $.trim($("input[id='controlled']").val());
event.preventDefault();
if (key === "") {

    if (value1 === "" && value2 === "" && value3 === "" && value4 === ""
            && value5 === "") {
        insertError
                .html("KEY required<br>at least a value required");

    } else {
        insertError.html("KEY required");
    }
} else {
    insertError.html("");

    if (value1 === "" && value2 === "" && value3 === "" && value4 === ""
            && value5 === "") {
        insertError.html("at least a value required");

    } else {
        if (id == "") {
            if (controlled == "") {
                return control();
            } else if (controlled== 'ok') {
                if (!confirm('are you sure?'))
                    return e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('form').submit();
            }

        } else {
            if (id != "") {
                if (!confirm('are you sure??'))
                    return e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('form').submit();
            }

        }

    }
}

};
```

if the form is compiled correctly and there is no id (so i am creating a new record on database and not editing) it returns a function that is an ajax call, it takes the key from the form and check in a servlet if there are records in the db with that key, then it returns some json.

here is the code:

```
function control() {
$
        .ajax({
            url : 'edit',
            data : {
                key : $('#key').val()
            },
            success : function(data, status, xhr) {
                var insertError = $("#insertError ");
                var labels = data.length;
                if (labels == 0) {
                    $('#controlled').val('ok');
                    return insertControl();

                } else if (dati > 0) {
                    insertError
                            .html("this key is already used");
                    return event.preventDefault();
                }

            },
            error : function(req, status, err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
            }
        })
```

}

the check works fine but it doesn't submit if i am creating a new label. just editing submits. I'm calling this function with onsubmit in the html file.

Comment: Can You pass `confirm` function?

Comment: it pass trough everything as i want, the only thing that it doesn't do is submit. it asks me the confirm, so it arrives even to the submit (already debugged, i'm sure)

Comment: I thing there something like this: `function confirm(){ /*show modal*/ if(confirm){return true;} return false;}`. And it always return false. Try use *callback* not return function for waiting for user action

Comment: i tried to put it in the callback (i took the entire control() and i have put it where i was calling it in the other function) it doesn't work.. maybe i have done it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for

> i tried to put it in the callback (i took the entire control() and i have put it where i was calling it in the other function) it doesn't work.. maybe i have done it in the wrong way?

It should be something like this:

```
if (id != "") {
  confirm('are you sure??', document.getElementById('form').submit)
  return e.preventDefault();
}

function confirm(question, callback){
  /*show modal*/
  /*action on user confirm*/
  function userConfirm(){
    callback();
  }
}
```

and with jQuery you can do

```
if (id != "") {
  confirm('are you sure??', $('#form').submit)
  return e.preventDefault();
}

function confirm(question, callback){
  /*show modal*/
  /*action on user confirm*/
  function userConfirm(){
    callback();
  }
}
```